# Uploading files more than 5 mb

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, web

I have an mvc4 web application.I need to upload a file which is more than 5MB.My upload is failing in this case.I aso tried
maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600"  in web config.How can i implement this?

Comment: What's the error message? What have to changed in web.config to try and resolve this?